# Opening link on new tab rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
<%= link_to image_tag("FooterGoogle.png", :size => "29x29", class: "img-rounded"), 'https://xxxxxxxxxx', target: "_blank" %>
```

this is the code I am trying to use to open the page on new tab rather than using on the same tab, according to me it should work perfectly fine, but I do not whats wrong its opening the page in same window itself.

someone please help me

Application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery_ui
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: can you show your application.js file?

Comment: Please show output html.

Comment: @SachinSingh what do you want with the js file?

Comment: @SachinSingh I have edited the question and put the application.js file content

Answer (score 0):

Normally this should work, I tried it in one of my applications:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/your-image.png", :size => "29x29", :class => "img-rounded"), 'http://google.com', :target => :blank %>
```

or this:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("/assets/your-image.png", :size => "29x29", :class => "img-rounded"), 'http://google.com', :target => :blank) %>
```

Which browser do you use?
And is the image loaded correctly?

Comment: both of these are not working, do you think there is something wrong with the jquery-ui or jquery-ujs

Comment: I just realised if I am logged into my website I am able to open those link in new page whereas if I am not logged it is opening in the same page.

Comment: Your link does not contain any javascript or something like that? Maybe a script is loaded if your are logged in, and is not loaded if you are logged out? But anyway it is really strange. If it is a normal link, it should definitely work.